# Online editing notification

Tags: editing, arcgis-online, geocortex

Does anyone know if there is a way to track or get email notifications if someone has made changes to attributes via online mapping? 
Our services are hosted through Arcserver 10.1 and an SDE database.

Currently we are using Geocortex Essentials for our online mapping needs, however I'm wondering if there this capability exists across the board?

I would just like some way of tracking changes and data management.

Thanks.

Comment: Not with standard arcgis-online/geocortex tools (custom code maybe) though FME server can detect and send email notifications - see http://fmepedia.safe.com/topic/FME-Server-Notification-Service

Comment: @Mapperz  I'm mainly a GIS user with basic python programming so I think this may be over my head! Thanks for suggesting FME but I don't think this is something our organization would move to at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocortex Essentials and its associated viewers do not currently have any out-of-the-box ability to send email notifications following an edit.

However, if you are using a workflow to present a form to edit attributes on a feature layer, then the workflow would be able to send an email following a successful edit.

You could also set up a database trigger in the ArcSDE database to fire off a message when a table is updated; however, that would not just be web edits, that would be when any row is updated by any client.

Comment: The database trigger could work, since the database for editing via the web is only used for web editing purposes! I would however like to somehow get the current user parsed into the "edit user" column for tracking edits...but this is proving difficult with workflow.

Comment: You should be able to get the current user in Workflow with the GetCurrentUser activity.  Exactly how to scoop up the current user in workflow might be best asked as a separate question, either here or on the Geocortex support forum directly.